# Why getting data from foreign key column in Entity Framework code-first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

This is my `Comment` class:

```
[Table("Comment")]
publicclass Comment
{
    public Comment()
    {
        SubComments = new HashSet<SubComment>();
    }

    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubComment> SubComments { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the `Subcomment` class:

```
[Table("SubComment")]
public class SubComment
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid Comment_ID { get; set; }
    public string text{ get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Comment1 { get; set; }
}
```

and this the `OnModelCreating` method on my context:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasMany(e => e.SubComments)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Comment1)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.Comment_ID);
```

Now for example if I run:

```
var test = DB.Comments.Where(w => w.text == "a");
```

Why does the `Comments` data also show the `subcomments` data?

I just need `Comments` data

Comment: did you inspect your object, or how do you know the navigation property was queried? was it stated in the sql? your query should not get the navigation properties joined in, until you query it, either by inspecting it in the debugger or enumerating the values.

Comment: i just select from sql in mvc,and when see datas  the Comments data also show the subcomments data

Comment: how do you see those?

Comment: when debugging in visual studio

Comment: then lazy loading will load these for you from the database. they are not actually retrieved.